# How do I install pgAdmin III for postgreSQL 9.2?

Tags: 12.10, postgresql

I have a Windows server that runs postgresql 9.2. I want to hit it using pgAdmin III from my Ubuntu 12.10 workstation box.

I installed pgAdmin III from synaptic and also tried direct download from postgreSQL site using software installer. Regardless, I can get only get pgAdmin III for postgresql 9.1. When I run pgAdmin III and point to my server I get an error message telling me that the database is 9.2 and my pgAdmin III is for 9.1, isn't compatible with 9.2.

I can access the server itself fine OK from the Ubuntu box - I have Python programs that hit the database with no problems - but I need pgAdmin III for 9.2 running under Ubuntu 12.10.

Is it available? Where do I get it?

Comment: pgAdmin 4 (pgadmin4) was released - [How to install pgAdmin 4 in desktop mode on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of 2014, this website describes the way to do it for Ubuntu and Debian: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Copy paste (2014-06-06) in case website goes offline, whatever happens:

**PostgreSQL packages for Debian and Ubuntu**

The PostgreSQL Global Development Group (PGDG) maintains an APT repository of PostgreSQL packages for Debian and Ubuntu located at http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/. We aim at building PostgreSQL server packages as well as extensions and modules packages on several Debian/Ubuntu releases for all PostgreSQL versions supported.
Currently, we support
Debian 6.0 (squeeze), 7.0 (wheezy), and unstable (sid) 64/32 bit (amd64/i386)
Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid), 12.04 (precise), 13.10 (saucy), 14.04 (trusty) 64/32 bit (amd64/i386)
PostgreSQL 8.4, 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4 beta
Server extensions such as Slony-I, various PL languages, and datatypes
Applications like pgadmin3, pgbouncer, and pgpool-II
Packages for older PostgreSQL versions and older Debian/Ubuntu distributions will continue to stay in the repository; updates for those will be provided on an ad-hoc basis.

**Quickstart**

Create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list. The distributions are called codename-pgdg. In the example, replace wheezy with the actual distribution you are using:

`deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wheezy-pgdg main`

(You may determine the codename of your distribution by running lsb_release -c.)
Import the repository key from https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc, update the package lists, and start installing packages:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 pgadmin3
```

Alternately, this shell script will do the above steps for you.
9.4 beta only: See FAQ on beta releases
Have a look at the FAQ.
Note: This repository provides "postgresql", "postgresql-contrib", and "postgresql-client" meta-packages that depend on the latest postgresql-x.y, ... packages, similar to the ones present in Debian and Ubuntu. Once a new PostgreSQL version is released, these meta-packages will be updated to depend on the new version. If you want to stay with a particular PostgreSQL version, you should install specific packages like "postgresql-9.3" instead of "postgresql".

Comment: If the instructions doesn't work when someone did `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wheezy-pgdg main`, 


do the following instead (from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt):
`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'`

Answer (score 62):

It is in the repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
```

or search the software center.

[image: software-center]

If that is the wrong version, you could use the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql):

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

If that does not work you can use the source and compile it yourself from [source](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/source.php).

Comment: This worked and is more to the point!

Comment: It is not in the s/w center, Ubuntu 16. But `sudo apt-get` worked

Comment: You're a legend!

Answer (score 4):

Version 16 of pgadmin3 ( http://www.pgadmin.org/visualtour16.php ) is required for Postgres 9.2 and it is *not* in the repo or that PPA for Ubunutu 12.10.

It looks like you have to build it or upgrade.

I've built it for 12.10:  https://copy.com/anB4E19CxdLW  - perhaps that binary will work for you if you are on 12.10.

If not and you need to build it yourself, make sure you install

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

For pgAdmin 4, you can also refer to this wiki page: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

I tried and installed pgAdmin 4 on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install postgresql-10 pgadmin4
```