# Cannot install pgadmin III

Tags: software-installation

I need to install pgadmin3 on Ubuntu, but it gives this message:

```
west@west-ThinkPad-T510:~$ sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 pgadmin3 : Depends: libwxbase3.0-0 (>= 3.0.2) but 3.0.0-2 is to be installed
            Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0 (>= 3.0.2) but 3.0.0-2 is to be installed
            Recommends: pgagent but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've googled it, but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` and then try again.

Comment: first try @Zacharee1 suggestion  and also please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220123/how-do-i-install-pgadmin-iii-for-postgresql-9-2)

Comment: Sorry for answering just now, busy week. Anyway I've tried the sudo apt-get update and noting has changed, it gives the same message.

Comment: He is a [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246946/postgis-ubuntu-installation-error-asking-for-dependencies) that helped me

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to finally install pgadmin3:

First I checked the available version on the repository:

```
apt-cache policy pgadmin3
```

Then installed that version (may change in time, use the proper version shown by the previous command):

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3=1.22.2-1 pgadmin-data=1.22.2-1
```

As Elder Geek points out, you need [to enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository/148645)

Comment: Uou might wish to note in your answer that installing pgadmin3 requires [enabling the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository/148645)

Comment: I tried so many unsuccessful things after enabling it that I forgot it in the end. Thank you, I edit my answer.