# How to install pgAdmin 4 in desktop mode on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, postgresql, pgadmin

How to install pgAdmin 4 in desktop mode? The [documentation](https://pgadmin.org/download/pip4.php) only details server mode.

Comment: The docker version sure was a lot easier and faster way of installing PGAdmin4. I spent a lot of time to do it the old way that was in the readme file. The way to access it then is in a browser window, point it to 0.0.0.0:5050 and it comes up real good. It loads quite fast BUT when I try to create a server with it it keeps saying that Postgresql is NOT running, however in PGAdmin3 Postgresql is running fine. Have read many comments saying what a poor product it is so use at your own risk!!!

Comment: https://kiahosseini.github.io/help/2016/10/18/installing-pgadmin4-ubuntu-16.04.html

Comment: Only pgadmin3 is available on apt (ubuntu 16.04). Any idea how to open a request to Canonical to include pgadmin4 in apt packages? What's the process of requesting an "app" to be included in a package manager?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka - check my answer below for the apt approach.

Comment: If anyone just wants pgAdmin3 you can simply install it using the Ubuntu Software application that's on all Ubuntu installations.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04 you can install `pgadmin4` with

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt install wget ca-certificates
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

I have tested this on 16.04.

[source for the above approach](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt)

Comment: Okay, one another thing i want to know that how do i start if i  installed it on server.

Comment: For Ubuntu based distros like Mint you may want to replace the `$(lsb_release -cs)` with the version of Ubuntu it's based on. For example, Mint Sarah (version 18) is based on Xenial and looks like this: `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'`

Comment: It looks like the ultimate solution, at least for Ubuntu +16.xx. Thanks !

Answer (score 165):

For *pgAdmin 4 v4.21* on *Ubuntu*, according to the [download page](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python-wheel/):

## Install dependencies, create a virtual environment, download, install & configure

#### Using Python2.x

```sh
sudo apt-get install virtualenv python-pip libpq-dev python-dev

cd
virtualenv pgadmin4
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate

pip install https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.21/pip/pgadmin4-4.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

#### Using Python3.6 (Preferred to avoid encoding related issues)

```sh
sudo apt-get install virtualenv python3-pip libpq-dev python3-dev

cd
virtualenv -p python3 pgadmin4
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate

pip3 install https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.21/pip/pgadmin4-4.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

### Configure

Override default paths and set it to single-user mode in the [local configuration file](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/server_deployment.html):

```sh
nano lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
```

For Python3.x:

```sh
nano lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
```

Write:

```sh
import os
DATA_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(u'~/.pgadmin/'))
LOG_FILE = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgadmin4.log')
SQLITE_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgadmin4.db')
SESSION_DB_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'sessions')
STORAGE_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'storage')
SERVER_MODE = False
```

### Run

```sh
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

For Python3.x:

```sh
python3 lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

### Access

Access at http://localhost:5050

### Exit

Exit with Ctrl-C

### Run again

```sh
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

For Python3.6

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python3 lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

### Make a shortcut

```sh
touch ~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
chmod +x ~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
nano ~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
```

Write:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

For Python3.6

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python3 lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Now you can just run it with a simpler command:

```sh
~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
```

### Python3 users

Replace [x] in Python3.6 with your respective version.

### Conflict with pgAdmin 3 configuration

`pgAdmin 4` will not start in the environment where `pgAdmin 3` was previously installed and used because of incompatible configuration in the `.pgadmin` directory. The simplest solution is to either clear that directory or tweak `config_local.py` to point to a clean new `.pgadmin4` directory.

Comment: 404 on that wget.

Comment: Great and easy method, can you please add instructions to upgrade to newer versions too? I had to delete my old virtualenv and create new one, that was only way i knew. Thanks again.

Comment: Added edit request for 4.1.5 (and noticed I wasn't logged in when I did so), in the meantime just make sure you use the 4.1.5 link: https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v1.5/pip/pgadmin4-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: I'd like to add that so I can quickly run it, I added this to my ~/.bashrc : 

alias pgadmin="source ~/pgadmin4/bin/activate && python ~/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py"

That way I can just type pgadmin and it launches, like it SHOULD out of the box.  You listening pgadmin?

Comment: FYI this has changed with the release of pgAdmin 4 v2: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/server_deployment.html#python

Comment: ftp link for v2.0 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.0/pip/pgadmin4-2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: Here is the correct link for FTP v2.1: https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.1/pip/pgadmin4-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: Why when I start pgAdmin and trying to hit `http://localhost:5050` in the browser it opens the pgAdmin menu, but when I try to hit `http://127.0.0.1:5050` it is not working an throws exceptions in the terminal (or after 10 minutes waiting start to return Unauthorized status codes)? Does someone have idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could the hard linking to python3.6 dependency in the `python3 lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py` be removed/replaced? That way the answer would be more future proof.

Comment: if you have fish , do `. bin/activate.fish` instead of `source bin/activate`

Comment: A simpler command to launch the server is `python -m pgadmin4.pgAdmin4`. This avoids having to reference paths directly in the site-packages directory.

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.04 which comes with Python 3.7 swap out every occurence of 3.6 with 3.7 in the Python 3.x instructions.

Comment: These instructions worked for me till the execution part where it threw the error " from werkzeug import url_encode
ImportError: cannot import name 'url_encode'". This is a problem due to using a later version of Werkzeug and can be fixed by  downgrading it by running "pip install werkzeug==0.16.0".

Comment: As per version 6.11 you need to add another config variable to config_local.py
AZURE_CREDENTIAL_CACHE_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'azurecredentialcache')
Or the application will throw exception that /var/lib/pgadmin/azurecredentialcache is not a directory

Answer (score 52):

Other option is to use docker and a docker image provided by thaJeztah - https://github.com/thaJeztah/pgadmin4-docker

```
$ docker run --rm -p 5050:5050 thajeztah/pgadmin4
```

Then to access a PostgreSQL DB instance from within pgadmin4 you should use the IP of the **host** instead of localhost and 127.0.0.1 since Docker will map those to the container itself.

The IP of a dockerised DB instance could be found with 2 steps:

- find the container ID of your db with:

  `docker ps`
- inspect the container_name to find its ip with:

  `docker inspect <ID from previous step>`

you are looking for something like "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3"

Comment: How can you make it see a dockerized postgres? localhost/127.0.0.1/container id did not work for me.

Comment: Can we set the IP static i.e. we don't have to update our application to point to new docker container IP every time we restart it

Comment: Nice, added a chromium application shortcut, and it's almost like having the actual application back-

Comment: Other way to connect the host database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Answer (score 4):

Finally, pgAdmin team created an [apt package for pgAdmin4](https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/)

It is supported on:

- Debian 9 (Stretch), 10 (Buster)
- Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial), 18.04 (Bionic), 19.10 (Eoan), 20.04 (Focal)

Now to install it you have to setup the the pgAdmin 4 offical repository, then you can install it

### Setup the repository

Install the public key for the repository (if not done previously)

```
curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add
```

Create the repository configuration file:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

### Install pgAdmin4

You can install both **Desktop** and **Web** modes:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

For **Desktop only**:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop
```

For **Web only**:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4-web
```

Source: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

Comment: I have installed the desktop version (6.1) and when entering I see there is a newer version (6.3) however when I run "sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop" I still get "pgadmin4-desktop is already the newest version (6.1).". How can I update it to 6.3 ?

Comment: @thanos.a try `sudo apt update` first, then `sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop`

Comment: It used to tell me that I am using the latest version 6.1. Once I updated my Ubuntu version from 20.04 to 21.04, I was able to install 6.3