# pgadmin 4 : sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

Tags: postgresql

I have already installed everything according [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-v1-0-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04) but when I try to run pgadmin 4, I get an error message like this:

```
> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such
> table: version
```

Also I don`t know how I should configure the pgadmin4.db file. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Solve this problem by deleting pgadmin4.db and reconfigure it use

```
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/setup.py
```

Then run

```
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```