# Problem install pgAdmin 4 v1.1 in desktop mode on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, python

Following previous post [How to install pgAdmin 4 in desktop mode on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-v1-1-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04), I had an error (can't find Python.h). Also someone mentioned about changing to python3, how would I go by doing this?

Thanks in advance.

```
pip install pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl

Processing ./pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl

Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Principal==0.4.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: blinker==1.3 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: unittest2==1.1.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: testscenarios==0.5.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: extras==0.0.3 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2==2.7.3 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib==1.0.3 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: traceback2==1.4.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-WTF==0.12 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz==2014.10 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse==0.1.19 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil==2.5.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.9.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: passlib==1.6.2 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent==0.11.13 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask==0.11.1 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ordereddict in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: WTForms==2.0.2 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Mail==0.9.1 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug==0.9.6 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: linecache2==1.0.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy==1.0.14 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Collecting psycopg2==2.6.2 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: python-mimeparse==1.5.1 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Collecting html5lib==1.0b3 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe==0.23 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click==6.6 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Collecting speaklater==1.3 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Collecting Flask-Security==1.7.5 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Collecting simplejson==3.6.5 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Collecting Babel==1.3 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: testtools==2.0.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Collecting pycrypto==2.6.1 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr==1.9.1 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Collecting Flask-Gravatar==0.4.2 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
  Using cached Flask_Gravatar-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Flask-Login==0.3.2 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.4.1 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting django-htmlmin==0.8.0 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: fixtures==2.0.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous==0.24 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Collecting Flask-Babel==0.11.1 (from pgadmin4==1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: argparse in /usr/lib/python2.7 (from unittest2==1.1.0->pgadmin4==1.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2, pycrypto
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2 ... error
  Complete output from command /home/edy/pgadmin4/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cFch6n/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpvOLZfypip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_errcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/tests
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090601 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
  In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:
  ./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for psycopg2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python.h` should be included in `python-dev`-Package. You can install this package with these commands:

```
sudo apt install python-dev
```

Comment: Thanks Phillip! Works like a charm. Oh, also thanks for formatting my post!