# pgadmin4 1.3 install Error loading script - /sqleditor/sqleditor

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

I had pgadmin4 v1.0, then I updated it without any problem to v1.1 and then v1.2.

After v1.3 was released I tried to do the update to v1.3. I followed the same steps as I did before. (Similar to [How to install pgAdmin 4 in desktop mode on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04) but using `conda` to create the virtual environment and with python 3.5, I also tried with `conda` + python 3.6 and with `virtualenv` and python 2.7 and I got the same result)

However, after the install was done I launched pgAdmin4 and I got the following error message that popped up in a modal:

```
Error loading script - /sqleditor/sqleditor
Error message
undefined
```

Nothing appears in the terminal.

This error appears in the browser console: `GET 
http://localhost:5050/lib/codemirror.js [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 6 ms]`

I rolled back to v1.2, which still works fine and I have no idea how to solve this issue.

I had the issue with both Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 with Firefox 52.0 64 bits.

Comment: What is your Browser name & version?

I tested with Chrome v.56 & Firefox v.52 and it is working fine.

Comment: @n33rma: Firefox 52.0 64 bits.

Comment: Can you provide error/screenshot from browser console?

Comment: Here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE5Co.png @n33rma thanks to enjoypb

Comment: This are from Windows system, I am not sure about Windows as I tested on Ubuntu only.

Comment: @n33rma This errors appears in Firefox console: `GET 
http://localhost:5050/lib/codemirror.js [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 6 ms]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to deactivate the virtualenv and create a new one.

```
 $  deactivate
```

In doing that you need to re-run setup.py:

If the path to v1.3 is different then make sure to change PGADMIN4_SRC to point to new location. 
Create a new web/config_local.py with the values you want.

Create the new venv

```
$ mkvirtualenv pgadmin4
and/or
$ workon pgadmin4
```

Then run

```
 $ python  $PGADMIN4_SRC/web/setup.py
```

Then you can start

```
 $ python  $PGADMIN4_SRC/web/pgAdmin4.py
```

The sqleditor/sqleditor error should no longer appear.

Comment: I tried and it didn't help. What is the `web` directory?

Comment: My instructions work for source - sorry.

Comment: My instructions work for source - sorry.
The web directory does not exist in the pip version.
Did you create a brand new virtualenv - like 
`virtualenv pgadmin4_1.3`