# PgAdmin 4 in standalone desktop mode-Error

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have followed the steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu), the 2nd Answer: Install dependencies, create a virtual environment, download, install & configure

When I execute the following command:

```
$ python3 lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

I get this error:

```
Can't locate revision identified by '84700139beb0'
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.